# How to install MySQL in Ubuntu Minimal 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, mysql, ubuntu-minimal

How can I install MySQL in Ubuntu Minimal 12.04?

When I try to `apt-get install mysql-server` (as root) even after `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` in a fresh install, I receive this:

```
# Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
# /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst: line 146: logger: command not found
# ATTENTION: An error has occured. More info is in the syslog!
# /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst: line 236: logger: command not found
# dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
# subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
# mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
# Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
```

Comment: What error is in your logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this

```
 sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
 sudo apt-get build-dep mysql-client5.5 mysql-server5.5
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

Try that and let me know how it foes for you..

Comment: I will try and post the results here

Comment: It's ok. just try that and also look out for other answers

Answer (score 0):

Since you are installing fresh,Please follow the steps to make clean uninstall.

apt-get purge mysql-server : This would remove the MySQL server

apt-get purge mysql-common  :This would remove the related MySQL files

rm -rf /var/lib/mysql      :This would delete the data folder of MySQL

rm -rf /etc/mysql

Once you have done,it would remove the MySQL completely from your machine.

Now try with the command to re-install by specifying the attributes

apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken

Hope it would help